# How can i use my DEFINE var file in my class file and use in class? in PHP

Tags: php

i have **config.php** file

```
<?php 
define(DBHOST, 'localhost');
define(DBNAME, 'new_shop_site');
define(DBUSER, 'root');
define(DBPASS, '');
 ?>
```

i try to get value of thes file in my **database.php** file

**database.php**
i try **1**

```
<?php 
    class database{
include_once("config/config.php");
        /*database credentials*/

        private static $host = DBHOST;
        private static $username = DBUSER;
        private static $pass = DBPASS;
        private static $dbname = DBNAME;
}
?>
```

then try **2**

```
<?php 
include_once("config/config.php");
    class database{
        /*database credentials*/

        private static $host = DBHOST;
        private static $username = DBUSER;
        private static $pass = DBPASS;
        private static $dbname = DBNAME;
}
?>
```

but not working.
how i get this value?

Comment: What does not working means exactly? Do you get any errors?

Comment: i got in try 1   `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'include_once' (T_INCLUDE_ONCE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)`

Comment: in try 2 `Notice: Use of undefined constant DBHOST - assumed 'DBHOST`

Comment: Please use your try 2 code. and Do you have double quotes around your constant names in your `define`? if not, you have to use double quotes or single quotes like this `define('DBHOST', 'localhost');` or `define("DBHOST", 'localhost');`